# Publish content from text area into another div

Tags: javascript, nicedit

It is like comment box. People are able to post their comments. Here I have one text area and and a div. If click one a button the comment has to be done. The comment should display in a div. I have given an external link, 
wich allows edit the text how they want.

```
<div id="sample">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://js.nicedit.com/nicEdit- latest.js"> </script> 
 <script type="text/javascript">
  //<![CDATA[
    bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() { nicEditors.allTextAreas() });
      //]]>
  </script>
  <h4>First Textarea</h4>
  <textarea name="area1" cols="40"></textarea>
</div>

<button type="submit" value="submit"
        style="background-color:red; color:#fff; 
        width:80px; height:50px; padding:5px;" onclick=""> Submit</button>

<div id="demo" style="width:300px; height:200px; border:1px solid #333;"></div>
```

Comment: And what is your exact question?

Comment: once click the button comment should display on div

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to give your `textarea` an Id value:

```
<textarea id="commentEditor" name="area1" cols="40"></textarea>
```

Then, in your script after you have created the editor, you need to create a function that can extract the text from your NicEdit box and put it into a div.

```
function SubmitComment {
    var editor = nicEditors.findEditor("commentEditor");  //find the editor by the ID
    var commentText = editor.getContent();    //this gets the actual text content from it

    //then assign the div with your content
    var commentDiv = document.getElementById('demo');
    commentDiv.innerHTML = commentText;

    //afterwards, you can clear the comment entry box
    editor.setContent("");
}
```

Make sure you tell your button to trigger this function

```
<button type="submit" value="submit"
    style="background-color:red; color:#fff; 
    width:80px; height:50px; padding:5px;" onclick="SubmitComment"> Submit</button>
```